# How to color code rows in a sharepoint list for each page?

Tags: jquery, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

Ive followed the guide on this site,

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/sagarp/sharepoint-2013-list-column-status-wise-change-row-color-usi/

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js">   </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $Text = $("td.ms-cellstyle.ms-vb2:contains('Approved')"); $Text.parent().css("background-  color", "#01DF3A");
    $Text = $("td.ms-cellstyle.ms-vb2:contains('Rejected')");
    $Text.parent().css("background-color", "#F90101");
    $Text = $("td.ms-cellstyle.ms-vb2:contains('Pending')");
    $Text.parent().css("background-color", "#EAC117");
});
</script>
```

This works! But...
The problem is that when the user visits the next page of results for the list, the color coding does not appear. It's as if the script does not run when the next page of the list loads.

Is there any way to ensure that the script runs?

My other idea for a solution would be to display all rows of the list. Currently only 30 items are being listed per page of the list. If all items were displayed then the script will run when the webpage loads and color code all the rows. If there's a way to do this it would also be extremely helpful.

Thank you.

Comment: I figured out by edditing the following line of code,within sharepoint designer, changes the number of items displayed for each page of the list.

<RowLimit Paged="TRUE">5000</RowLimit> 

Changing the number to some arbitraly large value seems to work. This solves my problem for now but is not the solution I would like.

Answer (score 4):

Since you are using SharePoint 2013 I would recommend you to consider a different approach, in SharePoint 2013 was introduced a so called `Client Rendering Mode (CSR)` which is intended for rendering of List Views and Forms using HTML and JavaScript.  To get acquainted with CSR follow these articles:

- [INTRODUCTION TO CLIENT-SIDE RENDERING IN SHAREPOINT 2013](http://www.rbradbrook.co.uk/blog/2013/04/14/introduction-to-client-side-rendering-in-sharepoint-2013/)
- [SharePoint 2013 Client Side Rendering: List Views](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/620110/SharePoint-Client-Side-Rendering-List-Views)

### How to highlight the rows using CSR

Below example demonstrates how to customize List View in order to highlight tasks rows (works properly for paged views)

Template code:

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc("clienttemplates.js", "SPClientTemplates", function() {

   SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides({
     OnPostRender: function(ctx) {

       var statusColors =  {
          'Not Started' : '#FFF1AD',  
          'In Progress' : '#FFD800',
          'Completed' : '#01DF3A' 
       };

       var rows = ctx.ListData.Row;
       for (var i=0;i<rows.length;i++)
       {
          var status = rows[i]["Status"];
          var rowId = GenerateIIDForListItem(ctx, rows[i]);
          var row = document.getElementById(rowId); 
          row.style.backgroundColor = statusColors[status];
       }
     }
   }); 

});
```

> Note: you have to specify the proper group name since in my case I am
>   using group named `Approvers`

### How to apply the changes

There are at least two options how to apply the changes:

1. Using [JSLink property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webpartpages.basexsltlistwebpart.jslink.aspx)
2. Place JavaScript template on page via `Script Editor`/`Content Editor`
   web parts

Here is how to apply the changes using the **second option**:

1. Switch the page into edit mode
2. Add `Script Editor` webpart right below the list view web part.
3. Put the specified code by wrapping it using `script` tag code into the Script Editor, for example: `<script type="text/javascript">{Template JS code goes here}</script>`
4. Save the page

### Results

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Drawbacks of the CSR method is you have to add a JS file somewhere and  configure the JSLink from each and every View Webpart. Two Views on one List on the same page also cause problems.

An alternative quick fix is to put ALL the logic inside One Calculated Column set to datatype=Number! so it evaluates the HTML/JavaScript on display

```
=[Status]
&"<img src='/_layouts/images/blank.gif' onload=""
this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.style.backgroundColor='#"
&IF([Status]="Approved","01DF3A",
IF([Status]="Rejected","F90101",
IF([Status]="Pending","EAC117","")))
&"';}"">"
```

Drawbacks of this method: only works on Views not in Forms, so you have to hide the Calculated Column in Forms (or not add them to the ContentTypes)
Column sorting doesn't work (as it doesn't evaluate the HTML/JS)

But hey.. it is a quick fix ... and works in 2010 as well :-)